# how to replace patterns sequentially in python when pattern includes duplicates

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list of patterns and a list of replacements. The pattern contains repeating elements but they correspond to different replacements.

```
txt=132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW
pattern=['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
REPLACEMENT=['why','nope','later','aha','genes']
```

The desired output would be 132whyasmnopewokdsllatersdwkaha239genes

What's the most efficient way to accomplish the sequential replacement?

Comment: What should be the output if your string is "HOME GO NOW GO NOW"? (switched the first two elements in pattern)

Comment: won't need to worry abt such as the pattern list is extracted sequentially

Comment: not "nope why later aha genes"? to clarify, you're only looking for certain words, the order of them doesn't matter? if the string were "GO GO GO GO GO", would the output be the same too?

Comment: so i knew the txt beforehand and knew it would contain elements in the pattern in that order and in the same length and it won't contain other elements in the pattern of GO * 5

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have control over when the pattern list is extracted? It would be easiest just to do the replacement when you do the extraction

Comment: @santoku - be aware that what's most efficient changes as your inputs change. For this trivial dataset all the solutions given are about the same. As the inputs grow what is most efficient changes drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt='132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
pattern=['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
REPLACEMENT=['why','nope','later','aha','genes']

for i,x in enumerate(pattern):
    txt = txt.replace(x,REPLACEMENT[i], 1)
```

For fun, here are the time tests, since the question asked for most efficient.

```
pattern=['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
REPLACEMENT=['why','nope','later','aha','genes']

t = time.time()
for z in xrange(1000000):
    txt = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
    for a,b in zip(pattern,REPLACEMENT):
        txt=txt.replace(a,b,1)
print time.time() - t

t = time.time()
for z in xrange(1000000):
    txt2 = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
    for i,x in enumerate(pattern):
        txt2 = txt2.replace(x,REPLACEMENT[i], 1)
print time.time() - t

t = time.time()
for z in xrange(1000000):
    txt3 = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
    x = dict(zip(reversed(pattern), reversed(REPLACEMENT)))
    for k in x:
      txt3 = txt3.replace(k,x[k], 1)
print time.time() - t


t = time.time()
for z in xrange(1000000):
    txt = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
    new_d = iter(REPLACEMENT)
    new_result = re.sub('\b' + '|'.join(pattern) + '\b', lambda _: next(new_d), txt)
print time.time() - t
```

Which results to:

```
2.57099986076
2.48500013351
3.50499987602
4.23699998856
```

As you can see, enumerate is slightly more efficient than zip, and the other two are not in the same ballpark.

Comment: After testing mine and the zip replace method, I found mine was indeed faster.

Comment: It's not always about speed. The `zip` replace method is more Pythonic IMO.

Comment: He actually stated what was the most efficient.  And how can you say that, they are essentially the same code save for I only parsing one list, you are parsing 2.  If anything mine is actually simpler and the most efficient.

Comment: Not here to argue, but I'm pretty sure the gains are marginal as `enumerate` and `zip` both return iterators. Besides, efficiency might translate to readability (in the long term), depending on your philosophy. Speed is just another metric.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the two lists at the same time, and only replace the first instance of the pattern each time:

```
for a,b in zip(pattern,REPLACEMENT):
    txt=txt.replace(a,b,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `dict` reduces the number of items you need to iterate over which may be valuable for some long inputs.

```
txt = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
pattern = ['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
REPLACEMENT = ['why','nope','later','aha','genes']

x = dict(zip(reversed(pattern), reversed(REPLACEMENT)))
for k in x:
  txt = txt.replace(k,x[k], 1)
print(txt)
```

Edit: for fun I added a benchmark to backup to illustrate that reducing the number of items you need to iterate over may be valuable for some long inputs. What is most *efficient* isn't always apparent when you are using a trivial test data set.

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*- 

def alpha(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt):
  for a,b in zip(pattern,REPLACEMENT):
    txt=txt.replace(a,b,1)

def beta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt):
  for i,x in enumerate(pattern):
    txt = txt.replace(x,REPLACEMENT[i], 1)

def gamma(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt):
  x = dict(zip(reversed(pattern), reversed(REPLACEMENT)))
  for k in x:
    txt = txt.replace(k,x[k], 1)

def delta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt):
  new_d = iter(REPLACEMENT)
  new_result = re.sub('\b' + '|'.join(pattern) + '\b', lambda _: next(new_d), txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import timeit, re

  txt = '132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW'
  pattern = ['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
  REPLACEMENT = ['why','nope','later','aha','genes']

  print("Trivial inputs:  len(pattern): {}, len(REPLACEMENT): {}, len(txt): {}".format(len(pattern), len(REPLACEMENT), len(txt)));
  print("alpha: ", timeit.timeit("alpha(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import alpha, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("beta:  ", timeit.timeit("beta( pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import beta,  txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("gamma: ", timeit.timeit("gamma(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import gamma, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("delta: ", timeit.timeit("delta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import delta, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("")

  txtcopy = txt
  patterncopy = pattern.copy()
  REPLACEMENTcopy = REPLACEMENT.copy()

  for _ in range(3):
    txt = txt + txtcopy
    pattern.extend(patterncopy)
    REPLACEMENT.extend(REPLACEMENTcopy)

  print("Small inputs: len(pattern): {}, len(REPLACEMENT): {}, len(txt): {}".format(len(pattern), len(REPLACEMENT), len(txt)));
  print("alpha: ", timeit.timeit("alpha(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import alpha, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("beta:  ", timeit.timeit("beta( pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import beta,  txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("gamma: ", timeit.timeit("gamma(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import gamma, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("delta: ", timeit.timeit("delta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import delta, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("")

  txt = txtcopy
  pattern = patterncopy.copy()
  REPLACEMENT = REPLACEMENTcopy.copy()

  for _ in range(300):
    txt = txt + txtcopy
    pattern.extend(patterncopy)
    REPLACEMENT.extend(REPLACEMENTcopy)

  print("Larger inputs: len(pattern): {}, len(REPLACEMENT): {}, len(txt): {}".format(len(pattern), len(REPLACEMENT), len(txt)));
  print("alpha: ", timeit.timeit("alpha(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import alpha, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("beta:  ", timeit.timeit("beta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import beta,  txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("gamma: ", timeit.timeit("gamma(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import gamma, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
  print("delta: ", timeit.timeit("delta(pattern, REPLACEMENT, txt)", setup="from __main__ import delta, txt, pattern, REPLACEMENT"))
```

Results:

```
Trivial inputs:  len(pattern): 5, len(REPLACEMENT): 5, len(txt): 33
alpha:  4.60048107800003
beta:   4.169088881999869
gamma:  5.7612637450001785
delta:  11.371387353000046

Small inputs: len(pattern): 20, len(REPLACEMENT): 20, len(txt): 132
alpha:  17.281149661999734
beta:   15.131949634000193
gamma:  7.339897444000144
delta:  26.50896787900001

Larger inputs: len(pattern): 1505, len(REPLACEMENT): 1505, len(txt): 9933
alpha:  18766.660852467998
beta:   17640.960064803
gamma:  64.01868645999639
delta:  901.3577002189995
```

So, for trivial inputs the `enumerate` solution is a tiny bit faster than zip and a lot faster than `iter`. When the length of the inputs is increased slightly then the cost of not removing duplicates starts to show and my solution runs in less than half the time. When a long input with lots of duplicates is run then @eatmeimadanish solution takes 27555% longer to complete than when duplicates are removed. Ouch.

Comment: Also much slower.

Comment: For all datasets?

Comment: Yes, this is MUCH slower and harder to read than the first two answers, which are similar in performance and readability.

Comment: I'll post my benchmarks as soon as the really slow cases are completed.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish - benchmarks don't back up your claim about MUCH slower. Your solution isn't even in the same ballpark.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this:

```
import re
txt = "132GOasmHOMEwokdslNOWsdwkGO239NOW"
pattern = ['GO','HOME','NOW','GO','NOW']
REPLACEMENT = ['why','nope','later','aha','genes'] 
txt1 = re.sub(pattern[1], REPLACEMENT[1], txt)
txt2 = re.sub(pattern[2], REPLACEMENT[2], txt1)
txt3 = re.sub(pattern[3], REPLACEMENT[3], txt2)
txt4 = re.sub(pattern[4], REPLACEMENT[4], txt3)
FINAL_TEXT = re.sub(pattern[5], REPLACEMENT[5], txt4)
print(FINAL_TEXT)
```

And the output:

```
"132whyasmnotwokdsllatersdwkaha239genes"
```

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or please edit. That cans help me to understand your opinion.

Comment: In his second comment the user (who asked) wrote: "i knew the txt beforehand and knew it would contain elements in the pattern in that order and in the same length and it won't contain other elements in the pattern of GO * 5"